# Handling akka persistence failures

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

I am building an application with Akka persistence.

I have to detect and handle the persistence failures properly. How is it possible? Will it throw any persistence exception?

Here is what I have till now

```
override def receiveRecover: Receive = {
...
}
override def receiveCommand: Receive = {
case WorkIsDone(workerId, workId, result) =>
persist(WorkDone(workId, result)) { event =>
        workData = workData.updated(WorkDone(workId, result))
        }

...     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When an error occurs it will throw an `onPersistFailure`

More information on [akka persistence failure section](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html#Failures) and also take a look at the different handlers when an error occurs [Persistence_status_handling](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html#Persistence_status_handling)